# Double trouble (Python)

Tags: computer-puzzle

Here's a Python program I like to call an Exam Code Generator

```
first_question = input("Input: ")

sec_one = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta', 'epsilon', 'zeta', 'eta', 'kappa', 'lambda', 'sigma', 'omega']
sec_two = ['aiko', 'ena', 'chizu', 'hoshi', 'kaiya', 'maiko', 'sayuri']
sec_three = ['ra', 'horus', 'anubis', 'hapi', 'osiris', 'maat', 'hathor', 'sekhmet']

code = ''

code += sec_one[(len(first_question) + ord(first_question[7 % len(first_question)]) + ord(first_question[25 % len(first_question)])) % len(sec_one)]

code += '-'

code += sec_two[ord(first_question[ord(first_question[35 % len(first_question)]) % len(first_question)]) % len(sec_two)]

code += '-'

chars = list(first_question)
chars = list(map(ord, chars))
code += sec_three[(sum(chars) - chars[77 % len(chars)]) % len(sec_three)]

print(code)
```

For example, inputting `hello there puzzling` produces `gamma-hoshi-hathor` and inputting `gamma-hoshi-hathor` produces `sigma-sayuri-horus`.

**What testing codes, when inputted, produce the same testing code?**

That is, if you input `a-b-c`, the output should be `a-b-c`.

---

*Note on solutions: your solution must be more elegant than just trying every single combination and testing if it produces the same combination. Try to actually analyze the program to produce your solution.*

*Note: Ian's solution (below) is correct, but I would like to see more than just a brute force. See my comment on the answer and the note above.*

Answer (score 1):

You've included `sum(list(map(ord, list(first_question))))`, which requires significantly more work to "analyze" than a very simple brute force.

```
sec_one = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta', 'epsilon', 'zeta', 'eta', 'kappa', 'lambda', 'sigma', 'omega']
sec_two = ['aiko', 'ena', 'chizu', 'hoshi', 'kaiya', 'maiko', 'sayuri']
sec_three = ['ra', 'horus', 'anubis', 'hapi', 'osiris', 'maat', 'hathor', 'sekhmet']

def ExamCodeGenerator(first_question):
  code = ''

  code += sec_one[(len(first_question) + ord(first_question[7 % len(first_question)]) + ord(first_question[25 % len(first_question)])) % len(sec_one)]

  code += '-'

  code += sec_two[ord(first_question[ord(first_question[35 % len(first_question)]) % len(first_question)]) % len(sec_two)]

  code += '-'

  chars = list(first_question)
  chars = list(map(ord, chars))
  code += sec_three[(sum(chars) - chars[77 % len(chars)]) % len(sec_three)]

  return code

for pre in sec_one:
  for mid in sec_two:
    for post in sec_three:
      inputString = pre + '-' + mid + '-' + post
      if inputString == ExamCodeGenerator(inputString):
        print(inputString)
```

I don't see how arduously computing `ord` of a whole list by hand is "more elegant".

> alpha-hoshi-maat
>  zeta-hoshi-anubis
>  eta-sayuri-hathor

Comment: If you look at the rest of the code, you should be able to eliminate some inputs based on those. You don't have to do it all analytically and you also don't have to do it all programmatically.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath What I'm saying is that "eliminate some inputs based on those" requires an `ord` at some point. Since that lookup table isn't provided (and who memorizes that, honestly?), a helper function is required to print out the table of `ord` values. Then, painstakingly going through each of the inputs and extracting the necessary values... nothing about that is elegant. Sorry.

Comment: What do you mean a lookup table isn't provided? And what do you mean who memorizes that? `ord` is ASCII codes! You don't have to do it all with a program, just think about it mathematically or analyze it by hand to some extent. That should give you a starting point for your program.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Unicode not ASCII.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath `ord('a')` is not `0`. It's some number bigger than 26. Ask me the ASCII code for a character 20 years ago, and I'd be able to tell you. Nowadays, that knowledge simply isn't relevant anymore. Computers abstract that (and for good reason).

Comment: What are you talking about? Who ever said that `ord("a")` was `0`? So what if it's greater than 26? What does that have to do with anything? Do you understand what Unicode and ASCII are? (By the way, Unicode and ASCII values are the same for the first 128 characters.) Almost every developer/software engineer/computer scientist I know has a basic knowledge of the most common Unicode and ASCII values. These values still are relevant and are used very frequently. Are you going to try to answer my question or are you going to try to keep justifying why the question is wrong?

Comment: (first 128 Unicode characters include all letters, numbers, and the most common symbols)

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Well, gee. I've been a software developer for 20+ years and I have to tell you that "almost every developer/software engineer/computer scientist I know _does not bother knowing_ Unicode and ASCII values", to take your words. Knowledge of these values is not still relevant; as a developer, you will never be expected to type `97` instead of `'a'`, nor will you have a need to interpret it yourself as such. That is literally what the computer is for. This just isn't a good puzzle because there is no snap trick to solving it, and it takes significantly less time to brute force.

Comment: The `ord` should add no additional difficulties to solving it. You can think of an `ord` like a substitution cipher if you want. In fact, replacing the letters with numbers might even make it easier!

Comment: @IanMacDonald Nevertheless there are developpers who are familiar with these values and there are situations where typing `97` is preferred. I think neither of you should use extreme words such as `every` and `never` - never use never, that's what everyone knows! For the puzzle, I also find it a bit strange, as the bruteforce method is so simple and thus already looks quite elegant to me.